# Averaging all values over a particular field

Tags: r

I have a data.table like this:

```
ID  SCORE
1   100
1   150
1   200
2   30
3   600
3   300
```

I want to create a table that averages the score of all the people with a particular ID and puts that into a new datatable (or the same one, doesnt matter). So, the new data.table should look like:

```
ID  SCORE
1   150
2   30
3   450
```

I really don't know where to begin. I think there should be an R function that does this already but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is easy to do. Assuming that your `data.table` is called `dt`, you can write:

```
dt[,lapply(.SD,mean),by='ID']
```

If you have many columns, and you want just the average of the SCORE column, you can write:

```
dt[,lapply(.SD,mean),by='ID',.SDcols='SCORE']
```

and if you want to exclude `NA`, then

```
dt[,lapply(.SD,mean,na.rm=TRUE),by='ID',.SDcols='SCORE']
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Or with `dplyr`

```
 df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(Score = mean(SCORE))
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

  ID Score
1  1   150
2  2    30
3  3   450
```

Answer (score 1):

Base package:

```
aggregate(. ~ ID, df, mean)

  ID SCORE
1  1   150
2  2    30
3  3   450
```

Using `sqldf`

```
sqldf("SELECT ID, AVG(SCORE) AS SCORE
      FROM df
      GROUP BY ID")
```